# Symfony 2 - Contact form and validation

Tags: oop, validation, symfony

I'm having trouble with contact form on Symfony 2.

Simple form

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input" />
    <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input" />
    <label for="text">Text: </label>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" class="input"></textarea>
</form>
```

I read the documentation about validations and form, but I didn't really understand what it was about.

I have two questions

1. where should post values go, I'm talking about action attribute in form.
2. how can I validate this simple contact form.

The best would be if you guys show me here or link to how to validate this simple form.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the action to any path in your routing. Example `<form action="{{ path(...) }}">`. From the path, there will be redirect to your controller. In your controller, you can validate the form. I will give you example.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="{{ path('form_contact') }}">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input" />
    <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input" />
    <label for="text">Text: </label>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" class="input"></textarea>
</form>
```

From here, this form will go through routing

```
// in your routing.yml
form_contact:
    pattern: contact
    defaults:
        _controller: YourNewBundle:Test:contact
```

Now, let's go to controller part

```
// TestController.php
public function contact(){
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->query->has('name') || $request->query->has('subject') || $request->query->has('text')){
        ...
    }
}
```

Just customize with your own code.